# Can i share ebook which i bought to multiple person without enabling them to download

Tags: copyright, authorship, publishing

Can i show share ebook which i bought to multiple person without enabling them to download ?. So i won't be making multiple copies of the ebook but will be showing it to multiple users. Is there any copyright violation in doing so?

Comment: Unless you are inviting people over to look at it on your computer, it is still distributing it and a violation of the copyright, regardless of "downloading" it. You seem to misunderstand how the internet works, content must be downloaded in order for it to be viewed, you aren't looking at a window on a server, the content (even here) is transmitted electronically (downloaded) on your computer and then displayed.

Comment: What is i make it available on a website such that at one time only one person is able to read it. And no one will able to download it. Like netflix does it for videos

Answer (score 1):

This will depend on the license under which you use the ebook. Some ebooks have a license which explicitly permits such sharing. In the absence of such permission, it will depend on how you plan to provide access to the ebook to those you plan to "share" with. Most ways of sharing would involve making a copy at some point in the process, which you may not do without permission. However, if you remove it from your computer(s) during the time that it is shared, so that it is never accessible on more than one computer or device at any one time, that might well be permissible, although I don;t know of a court case in point.

Comment: What is i  make it available on a website such that at one time only one person is able to read it. And no one will able to download it.

Comment: @sujeet14108 viewing it on a web page means the viewer has already downloaded it - that's how the web works.  You are still sending it to multiple people, just one at a time.  It doesn't change the fundamentals of copyright law.