# Why are Amazon and other vendors allowed to say "buy" an ebook or other digital asset when it is actually a license?

Tags: licensing, ownership, digital-contract

Amazon offers you the opportunity to buy a Kindle book. But you are  clearly not buying, rather [licensing](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/48687/), as they make quite clear.

This seems like false advertising; or alternately that a customer could demand to keep/own the item since that word was used.

Why are Amazon and other vendors able to do this without being stopped by lawsuits or legal enforcement?

Comment: I think essentially the word 'buy' does not have a detailed legal meaning and you can use it when offering a contract with whatever details you want. There is no law that says if you 'buy' or 'sell' something that some good must change ownership.

Comment: You're buying the license. What's wrong?

Comment: Thank you @quarague. As I understand the commercial law, words  used outside contracts are defined by their common meaning. You can't say that you sold something and then say that a specialized meaning of the word was used. A judge would rule in favor of what the ordinary man would understand.

Comment: Thank you @Greendrake . . A common understanding of "buy" is that you are buying. If the "Buy" button was instead labeled "Buy a license" that might be OK, but any judge would rule according to what the ordinary reasonable person would understand.

Comment: But any (?) judge would presumably take in to account the T&C the ordinary reasonable person agreed to when signing up for the service.

Comment: Suppose you can buy a paper train ticket for $10, but you can also use the $10 to get a barcode on your phone that lets you take the same train.  Should we use "buy" only in the first case?  I think most judges would agree that ordinary people understand "buy" not to apply only to tangible goods.

Comment: Also, what are you "keeping" or "owning" when you keep or own an e-book?  A sequence of ones and zeros?  That is not a tangible object.

Answer (score 3):

### You can “buy” a licence

Buy simply means exchanging money for goods or services. A licence is a service that can be bought.

Comment: Is there a  legal precedent, or a legal analysis of that? Amazon's wording is definitely "Buy the book", not "buy the license." I see that Amazon would argue this way in court, but I wonder if judges, or legal analysts, have looked at this.