# Where can I buy a license to use digital copyrighted music for piano lessons

Tags: copyright, licensing, music, education

I am a piano teacher and wish to display copyrighted music on a tablet for the kids to play music from.
I will arrange simplified music for them.
What sort of license do I need?
Where can I buy this?
Is there one agency which covers all songs?

Comment: Maybe it's better to ask if you legally need a license for this at all? If you have a license to install it/display it on your own tablet already, I don't see why you'd need an extra license to show that to someone else. Just like if I have a printed sheet of music, which is printed legally, simply showing that to someone else is not making a copy, so I don't need a license for that. The questions about rearranging the music and performing it are probably more interesting. Presumably the sheet music has some kind of implicit license that allows you to perform it privately in your own home.

Comment: I am using the music commercially, and uploading it onto many pupils tablets, I think this makes a difference

Comment: Then in that case you are making a copy for each student, and copying onto multiple student tablets.  You should specify that in the question. From how it's written currently, you say you're just "displaying" the music, which of course is not copying. "I will arrange simplified music for them" -- does that mean you will make the arrangement and then copy that arrangement as well, to each student's tablet? Again, I think it makes a difference, whether you're making extra copies or not.

Comment: I will make an arrangements to suit the level of the pupils I am teaching and then send a PDF to the pupils tablet (which I own and supply) The pupils use this tablet for home practice. (the tablet is locked down for use with my music only). By "displaying" I mean that a printed copy is not necessary or made.  If it makes a difference I could get the pupils to download a PDF each time they play the music an not store it on their device.

Comment: I will be making the arrangement available to view on many pupils tablets, either as a download PDF or page view on my site.

Comment: Law StackExchange can only tell you what the law says, not give you advice on how to solve your specific problem. See this related post: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/37827/can-i-share-ebook-which-i-bought-to-multiple-person-without-enabling-them-to-dow

Comment: Music Services are council run programs and can purchase an all encompassing license to use copyrighted works or £200 a year. This is not available to private music teachers. I still don't know how I can legally use such works and how I go about buying a licence, anyone know? thank you